# Mustache (PHP) Outputting associative array keys

Tags: php, templating, mustache

In Mustache can I print out the name of an associative array key instead of its value?

i.e. So instead of this:

```
$cars= array(
  'name'=>'ferrari', 'color'=>'red', 
  'name'=>'lambo', 'color'=>'yellow'
);
....
{{#cars}}
    {{name}} is {{color}}
{{/cars}}
```

I would prefer to have a data source with a smaller footprint:

```
$cars= array('ferrari'=>'red', 'lambo'=>'yellow');
....
{{#cars}}
    {{array_key_here}} is {{.}}
{{/cars}}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the OP has already moved on, but to anyone stumbling upon this post, I'd just like to point out that the reason this is not possible is because there is no predictable means of referencing anything in that array.

Think of a key in terms of a map, and you have more elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Or if you want to reverse index => value to value => index you can use [`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

Comment: I think this goes against the goal of having a light footprint for the data source... I think I would prefer to have a verbose but single data array than add more logic to the preparation of the data...